# Passing data between two tables from different activities - no databases involved in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Been struggling for days trying to pass data between two tables, one in activity 1 and the other in activity 2.

When I run the app, the first activity displays nicely, then would enter some data and when I click the send button, the app just closes and returns to the main menu of emulator. No error is written/mentioned so i am stuck. Please help.

This is part of the code:

```
Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    but1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public  void onClick(View v)     
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pick_Up.class);
            Bundle myData = new Bundle();

            ino.getText().toString(); //gets item number
            iname.getText().toString();  // gets item name
            iquantity.getText().toString(); //gets quantity
            ishop.getText().toString(); // gets shop name
            //assigns data to bundle
            myData.putString("ino", ino.getText().toString());
            myData.putString("iname", iname.getText().toString());
            myData.putString("iquantity", iquantity.getText().toString());
            myData.putString("ishop", ishop.getText().toString());

            intent.putExtra("myData",myData); // Adds extended data to intent
            startActivity(intent); //opens next activity
             }
    });  //End button
}
```

Code for Pick_Up.java

```
package com.example.allas;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class Pick_Up extends Activity {



TextView inotv,inametv,iquantitytv,ishoptv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pick_up);

    inotv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView0a);
    inametv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    iquantitytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ishoptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    inotv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1a);
    inametv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    iquantitytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    ishoptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);

    inotv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2a);
    inametv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
    iquantitytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
    ishoptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView23);

    inotv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3a);
    inametv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView31);
    iquantitytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView32);
    ishoptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView33);

    inotv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4a);
    inametv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView41);
    iquantitytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView42);
    ishoptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView43);

    inotv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5a);
    inametv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView51);
    iquantitytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView52);
    ishoptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView53);

    inotv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6a);
    inametv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView61);
    iquantitytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView62);
    ishoptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView63);

    inotv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7a);
    inametv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView71);
    iquantitytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView72);
    ishoptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView73);

    inotv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8a);
    inametv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView81);
    iquantitytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView82);
    ishoptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView83);

    inotv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9a);
    inametv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView91);
    iquantitytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView92);
    ishoptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView93);

    inotv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10a);
    inametv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView101);
    iquantitytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView102);
    ishoptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView103);

    inotv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11a);
    inametv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView111);
    iquantitytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView112);
    ishoptv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView113);

    try
    {
    Intent myLocalIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle myBundle = myLocalIntent.getExtras();

    String strino= myBundle.getString("ino");
    String striname = myBundle.getString("iname");
    String striquantity = myBundle.getString("iquantity");
    String strishop = myBundle.getString("ishop");

    inotv.setText(strino);
    inametv.setText(striname);
    iquantitytv.setText(striquantity));
    ishoptv.setText(strishop);

    myLocalIntent.putExtras(myBundle);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, myLocalIntent);
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: For sure there are errors in the logcat. Have a look there. Make sure you aren't filtering the logcat because you might miss something important. Also post the part of your layout XML describing`button1` and post the part of your code in `Pick_Up` class that tries to extract the extras from the incoming `Intent`

Answer (score 0):

USE PUT EXTRA TO SEND DATA

```
mIntent.putExtra("TEXT", studentnoText.gettext().toString());
mIntent.putExtra("TEXT_1", studentName.gettext().toString());
```

USE GET EXTRA TO GET DATA

```
String strNO,strName;
strNO= extras.getString("TEXT");
strName = extras.getString("TEXT_1");
```

Comment: My code could not be formatted, think it's too long. What can I do?

Comment: any past code what you try to send data one activity to other